# while coding decorator with typescript in visual code is giving error: TS1219:

Tags: typescript, decorator

using Version 4.0.5 of typescript and visual code v:1.50.1

while I am running the following:

```
    function sealed(constructor: Function) {
        Object.seal(constructor);
        Object.seal (constructor.prototype);
        console.log("hi")
       }

    @sealed
    class Greeter {
      greeting: string;
      constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
      }
      greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
      }
    }
    const a=new Greeter("Hi")
```

getting the error:
error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the experimental Decorators
option in your `tsconfig` or `jsconfig` to remove this warning."""

My `tsconfig.json` is

```
  {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "module": "es5",
           "moduleResolution": "node",
           "target": "es5",
           "sourceMap": true,
           "noImplicitAny": true,
           "removeComments": false,
           "experimentalDecorators": true
       }  
   }
```

Comment: Make sure that the entity that produces that message (VScode or `tsc`) reads the `tsconfig.json` file. My build command is `tsc --project .`.

Answer (score 2):

use this command for transpiling

```
tsc --experimentalDecorators fileName.ts
```